# Calculate the sum of a column and assign to a variable

Tags: hana

I want to perform sum of a column and assign the result into a variable . I have tried the following syntax.

```
declare variable double;
 variable:= select sum(cost) from retail 

or 
select sum(cost)from retail into variable.
```

Please suggest the correct syntax.

Comment: What is the datatype column "cost"

Answer (score 3):

In HANA's SQLScript this would be the syntax:

```
declare variable double; 
select sum(cost) into variable from retail;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use sql then Try below script:

```
Declare @variable int

Select @variable = sum(cost) from retail

Print @variable
```

Or

```
Declare @variable Numeric(18,2)

Select @variable = sum(cost) from retail

Print @variable
```